# Next frame after a movieclip in adobe flash actionscript 2.0

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, frame, movieclip, flash-cs6

I'm busy with a project in **Adobe Flash Actionsricpt 2.0**. And I have this imported video on one frame, but if i don't put `stop();` in the script of that frame, the video won't play, but if I do it won't go to the next frame.

Is there a code which makes the frame go to the next one when the movie is done playing?
I have tried

```
on(close){
```

gotoAndPlay(61)
}

And all of those with `on(...)` but they don't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to add code that identifies if your movie clip has reached its last frame. You need to find out how many frames that are in your video file and then tell Flash to do something after this final frame is reached.

```
if (_root.EXAMPLE_mc._currentframe == 1521)) {
    _root.gotoAndPlay("EXAMPLE FRAME NUMBER OR LABEL");
}
```

This assumes that your movie clip is 1521 frames long. Check in a video editor to be sure and replace that number.

Alternatively, you can find the end of the movie clip in FL CS3 and up and then can set a cue point there. Then, your refer to it just like you would a frame label. There is a good tutorial for this at [Dave Stiller's blog](http://www.quip.net/blog/2007/flash/how-to-use-flash-video-cue-points).